# Laravel quick start guide route return 404

Tags: laravel-4, routes, http-status-code-404

So I am a new Laravel user，I just went straight to the documentation to get started.but I get a question:
In app/routes.php,I  write like this:

```
Route::get('users',function() {
return 'hello';
});
Route::get('/',function() {
return View::make('hello');
});
```

When I hit

```
127.0.0.1/aerial/public/
```

it works fine;When hit:

```
127.0.0.1/aerial/public/index.php/users or 127.0.0.1/aerial/public/users or localhost/aerial/public/index.php/users
```

it returns 404;My environment  nginx.

Comment: Rather than saying "doesn't work", please specify what the exact problem is. E.g. "It returns a 404 error page".

Answer (score 0):

You should probably convert your `.htaccess` file in `public` directory to `nginx` format and make sure you have mod rewrite (or nginx module used for that) enabled